# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy haciendo un Proof of Work con angular ssr y estoy teniendo este error apenas comenzar..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he hecho mi tarea, y consulté al más sabio de la Red y me dijo que importara el `CommonModule` o el `BrowserModule`. Intente ambos modulos en los 2 modulos pero nada parece surgir efecto. ya no se que pasa.

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

el `app-routing.module.ts`. Aqui también intente importar solo el `HomeModule` en lugar de `HomeRoutingModule`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home-routing.module').then(m => m.HomeRoutingModule)
  }
];
```

el `home.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule
  ]
})
```

el `home-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PageComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

y el `page.component.html`

```
<ul *ngFor="let post of data">
  <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

No tengo ni idea del porque (ya que su nombre no tiene nada que ver con tu problema), pero en mi caso me ha servido, y es que si no importas el `FormModule` te va a ocurrir ese error, intenta colocarle el import y usarlo aqui en el **app.module.ts**:

```
import FormsModule from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule              //OJO AQUI!, tienes que colocar FormsModule aqui 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

En caso de que esto no sirva y te siga saliendo el mismo error, entonces haz lo mismo pero con el **modulo** de tu componente. esto extrañamente debe resolver el problema.

Comment: No, tampoco funcionó.